# Does two email programs eat twice the bandwidth?

Tags: email, bandwidth

I have Windows 10 email and Outlook on my computer and so every email gets downloaded in both places.  Does this use up twice as much bandwidth?  My internet bandwidth is getting used up so quickly.  I would like to uninstall Windows 10 but am afraid it might hurt my ability to get email.

Answer (score 2):

If both email programs are configured to download mail, then you are downloading every message twice.  Therefore, you are using twice the bandwidth for your email.

Email itself contains only text and does not use a lot of data, unless you are receiving a high number of large attachments.  If you are not receiving a lot of attachments, something else is eating up your data.

Comment: I also have an Android that has both Gmail and Email and a tablet that has both Gmail and Email.  Does this mean I am downloading my email six times?

Comment: @Cathy yes it does.  Edit, well yes and no.  It depends, mobile clients might not necessarily download attachments automatically.  That is a configurable option.  However, at the very least, if would be downloading the content of the message.

Comment: You are so helpful, thank you.  I am trying to choose between Outlook and Google for my email, calendar, and contact management.  I use Windows 10 on my laptop.  Is one better for me than the other?  I want to be sure that the laptop syncs properly to my phone.  Once I pick one, the best thing is to uninstall the other, correct?  Do you have an opinion on Google versus Outlook?  Many thanks.

Comment: @Cathy that is a matter of opinion and up to you.  If you found this answer helpful and correct, be sure to upvote and mark as the answer.